# How to access matched data in drop down menu in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I want to access matched data from `angularjs` like:

**Below one is list which i want to access:**

```
$scope.orderStatus = [
    { os: 'Open', value: 1 },
    { os: 'Completed', value: 2 },
    { os:'Cancelled',value: 3 }, 
    { os: 'Rejected', value: 4 }
]
```

**below one is for accessing list elements.**

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders" ng-if="order.OrderStatus==2">
```

**And below one is my drop down list.**

```
<div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">
    <select style="background: DarkSlateGrey; border-bottom: 2px; border-bottom-width: 4px; border-bottom-style: none; z-index: 2; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; Width: 98px; height: 25px; ">
        <option value="orders">Order</option>
        <option value="open">Open</option>
        <option value="complete">Completed</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="reject">Rejected</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

How to bind it with modal and how do I access individual details when I click on particular order elements?

Comment: can you please explain in brief? 'How to bind it with modal and how do I access individual details when I click on particular order elements?'

Comment: it would be better if you can share fiddle

Comment: @Sravan   suppose, when I click on "complete" in drop down menu then it should show matched data in complete list and so on.
how to correct above one so that it could access data on clicking.

Comment: @Vilas  for example: when I click on "complete" in drop down menu then it should show matched data in complete list and so on. how to correct above one so that it could access data on clicking.

Comment: @AnkitRaman I thing you missed ng-model, checkout on their official site.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 1):

Accrdng to my view to ur prblm blw solution will work

Add **ng-model="someVariable"** in **select** Tag.. so that when you choose any dropdown values, then that will be selected and **someVariable** is having that value.. Use that variable and access other things.

Comment: Thank you,I did by your way.now i want to access all the data from all Lists (Open,completed,Cancel,Reject).how do I make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to get the Power of `angularJs` you have to use the `model` which allows the `two-way binding` in angular.

Here is the solution for your problem.

This will be the main change.

```
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option ng-repeat="option in orderStatus" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.os}}</option>
</select>
```

**1) In the above code, I assigned `ng-model="selected"` to the select box which holds the selected value.**

**2) I repeated ng-options from your object so the value will be Dynamic.**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in orders | filter : selected">
    {{ x.Name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**3) I repeated the `orders` and used `angular filter` using the selected value. so that the orders will be filtered according to that value**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">
    <select style=" border-bottom: 2px; border-bottom-width: 4px; border-bottom-style: none; z-index: 2; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; Width: 98px; height: 25px; " ng-model="selected">
      <option value="">ALL</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in orderStatus" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.os}}</option>
        
    </select>
</label>
</div>
{{selected}}
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in orders | filter : selected">
    {{ x.Name }}
  </li>
</ul>

<p>All these Order have OrderStatus. {{selected}}</p>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.orderStatus = [
    { os: 'Open', value: 1 },{ os: 'Completed', value: 2 },{os:'Cancelled',value: 3 },  { os: 'Rejected', value: 4 }
]
    $scope.orders = [
        { OrderStatus: 2 , Name: 'order1'},
        { OrderStatus: 3 , Name: 'order2'},
        { OrderStatus: 3, Name: 'order3'},
        { OrderStatus: 1 , Name: 'order4'},
        { OrderStatus: 2 , Name: 'order5'},
        { OrderStatus: 4 , Name: 'order6'},
        { OrderStatus: 2 , Name: 'order7'}
        
    ];
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AVPa9zkXluyvIs3gM97K?p=preview)

Comment: suppose when I clicked on "All" then How do I access all data from List(Open,Complete,Cancel,Reject) in same place?

Comment: Adding the same to answer

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: @AnkitRaman, if this answer helped you, you can upvote and vote it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` attribute for options and `ng-model` to bind your search property with selected value. Then filter your orders by search value with `filter` or display only values that you need with `ng-if` as you suggested.

```
<select ng-model="searchParams.OrderStatus" ng-options="status.value as status.os for status in orderStatus"></select>
```

Now `$scope.searchParams.OrderStatus` contains selected order status. Use it in `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter: searchParams">
```

Comment: suppose when I clicked on "All" then How do I access all data from List(Open,Complete,Cancel,Reject) in same place?

Comment: Just clear the value you are filtering by

`<a ng-click="searchParams.OrderStatus = undefined">All</a>`